# URL Rewriting with multiple rules: wrong $_GET variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm very new to URL rewriting. What I'd like to achieve is to have 2 main rules:

1. Hide all .php extensions
2. Rewrite `domain.com/p.php?id=1` to `domain.com/p/1`

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule   ^p/(.+)$   p.php?id=$1   [L]
```

This seemed to work at first: all .php extensions are hidden, and typing domain.com/p/1 displayed domain.com/p.php?id=1.

However, I've just realized that the PHP GET method on this page picks up a wrong value: whereas I want it to pick up `1`, it actually picks up `1.php/1`. I didn't notice it at first because the database query based on `$_GET` actually works, which seems odd to me now that I know the value is wrong.

How could I make the combination of these two rewrite rules work as intended?

Thank you!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php` is the poison poll here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+p\.php\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /p/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^p/([0-9]+)/?$ /p.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi! Should I place this after the first rule I wrote, `^(.*)$ $1.php` ? If I only keep this, it seems like `domain.com/test` does not rewrite to `domain.com/test.php` and throws a 404.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to rewrite the numerical values, you should restrict your second rule:

```
RewriteRule   ^p/(\d+)$   p.php?id=$1   [L]
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for you reply! However, this rule seems to trigger a 500 Internal Server Error. :-/